# Horizontal center items inside NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I have the following Navigation Drawer menu setup:

Main layout **activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My menu **activity_main_drawer.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item"
        android:title=""/>
</menu>
```

Menu item **menu_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu Title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result I get is this:

[Result i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PIit.png)

Instead I want it to be horizontally centered, what did I do wrong here? I have tried many fixes with the custom layout's gravity (**menu_item.xml**) as well as the items, nothing seems to work.

I don't know if the `app:actionLayout` in the menu can be centered or not at all, if not please tell me what is the correct way to make an item like that with the alignment I want. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated the answer, please have a look, and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the

> menu_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Menu Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this, the result was messy, please notice that my NavigationDrawableView has a limited width of 150dp.

Comment: @Anas can you upload the new screenshot?, i can help you with the changes.

Comment: I added padding to the item layout and it looks centered now

Answer (score -3):

Try this, menu_item.xml you can set gravity to center_horizontal.

Comment: Would you please be more specific?

Comment: I have specified bro.